# How to disable automatic unindent of comments in Python?

Tags: indentation, filetype-python

I start vanilla vim8 `$ vim -u NONE` with these settings:

```
:set ft=python
:set smartindent
:set cinkeys-=0#
```

When I enter in insertion mode the following:

```
    Hello
    #
```

The `#` is automatically unindent as follow:

```
    Hello
#
```

Of course if I enable `:set cindent` everything works because `cinkeys` is now taken in account.

My question is why is `#` automatically moved left while `cindent` is disabled? Is there any better solution other than using an auto command?

```
autocmd FileType python setlocal cindent
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typing the `#` character causes an outdent because you have set `'smartindent'`, which is designed for C-like languages (where `#` indicates the start of a preprocessor directive).

Quoting from the output of `:help 'smartindent'`

> When typing '#' as the first character in a new line, the indent for
>       that line is removed, the '#' is put in the first column.  The indent
>       is restored for the next line.  **If you don't want this, use this
>       mapping: ":inoremap # X^H#", where ^H is entered with CTRL-V CTRL-H.**
>       When using the ">>" command, lines starting with '#' are not shifted
>       right.

*(emphasis mine)*

If you wish to continue using `'cindent'` but want a better way of setting it than an autocommand, you can simply place a file containing:

```
setlocal cindent
```

In the location: `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/python.vim`.

Alternatively, you could simply turn off `'smartindent'` and use `'autoindent'`, or, perhaps best, look into obtaining a plugin that is designed specifically to implement Python indentation. [Here's one](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=974). [Here's another](https://github.com/hynek/vim-python-pep8-indent).